# Odd PowerShell behavior and Add-Member

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Can someone help me understand why the $_ works differently for the Add-Member function than it seems to for other PowerShell functions?  There must be some nuance that I am missing here.

Using the sample CSV file below, the first 3 examples work fine.  The fourth, which seems pretty straightforward, does not.  The error Powershell returns is:

```
The variable '$_' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
```

Is this "normal" or have I miscoded something?

Thanks in advance.

```
Test.csv
Column1,Column2, Column3
Rock,1,abc
Paper,2,efg
Scissors,3,hij

$obj = Import-CSV "C:\test.csv"

(1) $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IdNumber -value "ROCK" -PassThru| Format-Table

(2) $obj | ForEach-Object { $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IdNumber -value $_.Column1 ; $_} | Format-Table

(3) $obj | ForEach-Object { Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IdNumber -value $_.Column1 ; $_ } | Format-Table

(4) $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IdNumber -value $_.Column1 -PassThru| Format-Table
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IdNumber -value $_.Column1 -PassThru
```

You are accessing `$_` outside of a pipeline bound context e.g. inside a foreach-object expression or within a scriptblock value specified for a pipeline bound parameter. The `Value` parameter is not pipeline bound.  If it were you would be able to do this:

```
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IdNumber -value {$_.Column1} -PassThru
```

As it stands, the easiest way to do what you want is:

```
$obj | ForEach-Object { Add-Member -Inp $_ NoteProperty -Name IdNumber -Value $_.Column1 -PassThru } | Format-Table
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction :) Not sure what I was thinking about. If my answer were true, neither `where`, `foreach`, `select`(calculated properties), or the rest of PowerShell would have worked. :P

Comment: @Graimer No problem. Happens to the best of us. :-)  Keep up the good work!

Comment: @KeithHill -- Thank you so much for dropping by and answering. I have gotten quite a few good tips from your blog as well.  I wish the Powers That Be would make Add-Member automatically passthru the object and accept the $_ but I can also see pretty good readability in coding it as you suggested in that last line. All the best!